# c# async method not showing under class

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Quick question, I am trying to execute a method asynchronously and send out 3 threads. I made a small method and tried it both in the Program.cs class, as well as a separate class, but it still does not show up as an available method to execute. Someone told me in a previous question that you can't execute the async task in main, you have to do it in a separate method.

So I created a separate method, however I'm just not sure how to call it. Each task returns a datatable.

How would I call the async method to execute from main? Should my interrogation of the results be in main?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
}

public async void job()
{
    SchoolData CSD = new SchoolData();
    FloData FD = new FloData();
    GiftData GD = new GiftData();

    List<Task<DataTable>> tasks = new List<Task<DataTable>>();

    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CSD.getSchool()));
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => FD.getFlo()));
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GD.getGift()));

    var Results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Immediately, you need to add `static` to your method to make it show up.  But your larger code structure is wrong if you want to use the results of the tasks.  What are you trying to accomplish with the returned data?

Comment: My, this code looks familiar.  Also, you're not using `await` in the method, so adding `async` to the signature is pointless.

Comment: @Will he is awaiting `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: @dcastro ah, there it is.  BRB, more coffee.

Comment: Steve, I want to take all 3 datatables returning from the method, combine it into a dataset, and I will do a sql bulk insert for each table.

Answer (score 6):

> but it still does not show up as an available method to execute.

Because `Main` is static, and your method isn't. Mark it as `static`:

```
public static async Task JobAsync()
```

Note i changed your method to `async Task` instead of `async void`. The latter is ment only for top level event handlers. Also, note that if you execute `JobAsync` in `Main`, you'll have to explicitly wait on it using `JobAsync().Wait()` (you should only use `Wait` inside a console applications main method as it synchronously blocks. For all other cases, `await` should be used to asynchronously wait).

> how would I interrogate the results?

After you asynchronously wait on all tasks, you can access their `Result` property:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CSD.getSchool()));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => FD.getFlo()));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GD.getGift()));

var Results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
   // Access the result property
   var result = task.Result;
}
```

Comment: Will doing it this way at least let the 3 tasks go out simultaneously? My goal is to have them simultaneously getting data in separate threads to increase performance.

Comment: They will execute in parallel, yes.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again but last question, since technically I'd be using a task, how would I interrogate the results? It comes back as a task, so how do I get my 3 datatables out of that?